# JNDI configuration in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, jndi

I am trying to set up JNDI lookup in web application to be deployed in Tomcat 7. I have specified following properties in `jndi.properties` file:

> java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory,
>       java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces,
>       java.naming.provider.url=localhost:1199

But when i get initial context and inspecting its attributes it reveals that `java.naming.factory.initial` changes to `org.apache.naming.java.JavaURLContextFactory` and all other properties remains same as in the `jndi.properties` file.I dont understand why this single property gets changes ? How can i prevent this and force tomcat to use property i have specified ?

Comment: Similar: [*How to configure jndi DataSource in Tomcat 7*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28368103/642706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the JNDI properties should be vendor specific, What you trying to put is for Jboss JNDI properties, and may have been reverting to for Tomcat Specific Proerties. Although you can try to overwrite them programatically, it might not work properly.

Comment: I already did that,modified properties programatically and it worked but my question was, why they did not worked directly from jndi.properties ? Because i wrote a stand alone client which uses jndi.properties and it works fine, but the same code and same jndi.properties file did not work in Tomcat.It changes initial context factory to JavaURLContextFactory though i specified NamingContextFactory.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all this stuff into a Resource element in your META-INF/context.xml file, and look up that resource via a java:comp/env URL. That's what Tomcat is trying to set up here: an object factory for that namespace.

Comment: I tried with this as well and it worked.But since i am looking up remote jndi tree and my Tomcat app is a client i thought configuring resources in tomcat is not a good idea. One more thing is jndi.properties should work regardless of what resources i configure in client,cause i am not looking up into client's JNDI tree, rather server's JNDI tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should append your properties to your catalina.properties file,it's under your $tomcat_home/conf.