# How to configure jndi DataSource in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, jndi

I need to deploy our web application in tomcat 7.but my application use JNDI data source. how to create jndi DataSource in Tomcat 7

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Tomcat Manual: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

(Hint: Google String was "jndi datasource tomcat 7")

Comment: yes try but document show resource ref add in WEB-INF/web.xml file. i needed this without modify web.xml because i dont have permission to modify web.xml

Comment: @Sunilshakya Why not? As a matter of fact Tomcat doesn't need the resource-ref, just the entries in Context.xml, but it's unreasonable to have been given this task without thr permissions necessary to carry it out.

Answer (score 0):

I can show how I do it in Tomcat 9. This may or may not work in Tomcat 7. FYI, [Tomcat 7 seems to be](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Please-help-EOL-TOMCAT-7-and-8-5-td5073688.html) in [maintenance-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode).

In my situation, I want to store settings such as database access info *outside* my web-app’s [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)) file. This gives me flexibility for each of my development, testing, and production servers to have their own settings resident in their file system. Ditto for my customers running my app. No need to edit the WAR file, or produce individualized WAR files, if these settings are kept externally, living on each server separately. And no need to re-edit the WAR file when settings change or when a new version of the WAR file arrives.

In the Tomcat "home" folder, or Tomcat "base" folder if you’ve designated one, go into the `conf` folder to create a `Catalina` folder. ”Catalina” is the name of the Tomcat engine. Nest within that a new folder named `localhost`, the name of your host. Within that create an XML file, named the name of your context.

I find that `app-name-goes-here.xml` approach is a simple place to store these settings external to my web-app’s [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)) file, yet not having to mess with Tomcat's own files. This approach is rather obtusely documented in the middle bullet beginning "In individual files" in the *Defining a context* section of [*The Context Container*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html) page of the *Tomcat Configuration Reference*.

For example, here is a screenshot of my app named *TickTock*, using a "base" folder outside the Tomcat folder.

[image: screenshot of "base" folder > "conf" > "Catalina" > "localhost" > ticktock.xml]

In that XML file you can define things like environment variables such as a "DEV" versus "PROD" flag or a [feature toggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle), and resources such as a JDBC [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) singleton to be instantiated. These items are managed by Tomcat's own implementation of an [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol)-like server that can be accessed via [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface).

Here is a nearly-realistic example of my `ticktock.xml` file.

Notice the first few attributes of each attribute; these are standard, defined by the Servlet spec and documented here for [environment entries](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Environment_Entries), and here for [resource entries](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Definitions).

And notice how the `Resource` element has additional attributes. These are specific the particular resource. In this case, the particular resource is [this Postgres JDBC driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org).

```xml
<Context>

    <!-- Domain: DEV, TEST, PROD -->
    <Environment
            name = "work.basil.ticktock.deployment-mode"
            description = "Signals whether to run this web-app with development, testing, or production settings."
            type = "java.lang.String"
            value = "DEV"
            override = "false"
            />

     <Resource
             name = "jdbc/ticktockdb"
             description = "Database used by the TickTock app."
             type = "javax.sql.DataSource"
             auth = "Container"
             singleton = "true"

             driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
             url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/ticktockdb"
             username = "TickTockApp"
             password = "pw"
             maxTotal = "20"
             maxIdle = "10"
             maxWaitMillis = "-1"
             />

</Context>
```

How get an object for either this environment entry or this resource entry?

First, get a JNDI "context" from which to access these entries.

```xml
Context ctx = new InitialContext ();
```

You will also need trap for any [`NamingException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.naming/javax/naming/NamingException.html), but I'll omit that code.

You can dump all your environment entries with this simple code. I use lambda syntax here, but you can just as well use classic Java syntax.

```xml
// Read all properties.
System.out.println ( "INFO - Dumping bindings for environment variables." );
ctx.listBindings ( "java:comp/env" ).asIterator ().forEachRemaining (
        ( Binding binding ) -> {
            String msg = binding.getName () + " : " + binding.getObject ();
            System.out.println ( msg );
            this.add ( new Paragraph ( msg ) );
        } );
```

Or fetch a specific one.

```java
String deployMode = ( String ) ctx.lookup( "java:comp/env/work.basil.ticktock.deployment-mode" );
```

To get a `DataSource` object, we must cast the `Object` returned by JNDI.

```java
DataSource ds = ( DataSource ) ctx.lookup( "java:/comp/env/jdbc/ticktockdb" );
```

This is all we need!

You will see other discussions about additional configuration for further Servlet or Tomcat features that provide another layer of indirection, so the naming within your code does not need to match the names in the LDAP or other server being accessed by JNDI. While I am not sure, I believe that if the extra layer of indirection is not necessary for our web-app project, our environment or resource request will be provided directly from the naming server if we specify the entire JNDI lookup string as seen here, starting with `java:/comp/env` rather than just the ending part `jdbc/ticktockdb`. If anyone would like to clarify this, please post a comment or edit this Answer.

### JDBC driver

[JDBC drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) are problematic in a Servlet container. Long story short, you should *not* bundle the JDBC driver with your web-app in its WAR file.

Instead, you want to load the JDBC driver on the *Common* class loader or possibly the *Shared* class loader. For the *Common* class loader to auto-detect your JDBC driver, drop its [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) file into Tomcat's `lib` folder (or if using a designated "base" folder as seen above, create a `lib` folder as seen above, and deposit your driver’s JAR there).

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Comment: The `Resource` definition should be placed into the META-INF/Context.xml entry in the WAR fie. Tomcat will deploy it from there. The enormous picture isn't really relevant, just a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: @user207421 And when you want different settings on your development server than your testing server, and different settings again on your production server? Embedding your settings within your WAR file is counterproductive and downright dangerous to have to rely on either automated or manual editing of the WAR file. For some of us, these settings are best kept *outside* the WAR file, not within it. But to each his own. What you mention, and what I discuss, are two of the multiple ways to set these settings. If you really want to hard-code these settings within your app, skip JNDI altogether.